# Exercise 2.2.4 from Complex geometry by Daniel Huybrechts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

This question is the poini ix) of the exercise $2.2.4$ coming from page 68 of the book Compex Geometry by Daniel Huybrechts.
Here i write the question:
we have two holomorphic vector bundle $E,F$ given by the cocycles $\psi_{ij}$ and $\psi^{'}_{ij}$ respectively.
The exercise says that if for all $x \in U_i\cap U_j$ the matrix of $\{ \psi^{'}_{ij} \}$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix} \psi_{ij}&* \\ 0& \phi_{ij}  \end{bmatrix}$ than $E$ is a holomorphic sub-bundle of $F$, i.e. there exist a canonical injection $E \subset F$.
Conversely if $E$ is a sub-bundle of $F$ we can find cocycles of this form and the cokernel $F/E$ is described by the cocycles $\phi_{ij}$.
Can someone helping to show this fact?

Comment: What have you tried?This is a straightforward application of the definition of a vector bundle using cocycles.

Comment: I'm trying to use the classical definition of vector bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a morphism of vector bundle is uniquely determined by a collection of holomorphic maps 
$$\lbrace f_\alpha: U_\alpha \longrightarrow\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{C}) \rbrace_\alpha $$ such that $f_\alpha=\psi'_{\alpha \beta}f_\beta\psi_{\beta \alpha }$. At this point you can define $$f_\alpha=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{I}_m\\
O \\
 \end{array} \right].$$